# Closure in node js not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I have this piece of code:

```
var responses = [];
for( var i=0; i < Number(process.argv[2]); i++) {
    responses.push(function () {
        var index = i;
        function bar() {
            console.log(index);
        }
        return bar;
    }());
}

responses.forEach(function(d){
    d();
});
```

where a closure is created by using an interim variable `index`. This outputs 
`0 
1`

as expected, printing the values I want to capture in a closure.

A similar code as http get callback doesn't work.

```
var http = require("http");

var urls = ["http://yahoo.com","http://google.com"];

for( var i=0; i < urls.length; i++) {
   http.get( urls[i] , function(res) {
        var j = i;
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        res.on("data", function(d) {
            console.log(j);
        });
    });
}
```

This code outputs: 

`2
2`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var j = i;` will set the value of `i` which is length of the array on first response and that is the reason you get `2` every time you log it.

Invoke a anonymous function as a second argument of `http.get` which will return inner function to handle response and it will also remember the environment in which it is created. Value of passed argument `i` will be there in the memory to be used later.

Try this:

```js
var http = require("http");

var urls = ["http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com"];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  http.get(urls[i], (function(i) {
    return function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf-8');
      res.on("data", function(d) {
        console.log(i);
      });
    }
  })(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I eventually figured out that the callback is only run at the time of execution and hence the value of i remains `2` in my case. something like this will work too:   ` var responseHandler = curry( function(i,res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');
            res.on("data", function(d) {
                console.log(i);
            });
    });
    http.get( urls[i] , responseHandler(i));`

Comment: _I'm glad it helped!_

Comment: Yes, callback is nothing but an expression of function which executes later..in your case when data is received from server..we are invoking a function while attaching event and return a inner function which works as callback function..As new scope is created, returned function remembers the value of `i`

Answer (score 1):

There is no block scope in javascript(es5). So the for loop that you used won't do the trick., Instead try:

```
  urls.forEach(function(url, i){
      http.get( url , function(res) {           
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        res.on("data", function(d) {
            console.log(i);
        });
    });
```